# jboss with less memory

Tags: java, memory, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have now 1gb ram at work(i hope that will change soon) and jboss takes almost half of it and that is too much, i turned off logging to file, what more can i do to reduce memory usage ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can limit the maximum memory used using the -Xmx parameter, as in any java process.
Edit the $JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.conf and set this parameter to the desired maximum memory you want to allocate to JBoss.

Also, you can remove from the deploy directory of the server configuration you are using, the services you are not using. To be sure about what files you must remove in order to remove unused services, check the [documentation](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossas/freezone/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/beta500/html/index.html)

Comment: JBoss 6.x tunning/slimming info can be found [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss6xTuningSlimming)

Answer (score 5):

Which configuration are you using? JBoss comes with 3 [standard server configurations](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossas/freezone/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/beta500/html/ch03s02.html)

- The ***minimal*** configuration starts the core server container without any of the enterprise services. It is a good starting point if you want to build a customized version of JBoss AS that only contains the services you need.
- The ***default*** configuration is the mostly common used configuration for application developers. It supports the standard J2EE 1.4 and most of the Java EE 5.0 programming APIs (e.g., JSF and EJB3).
- The ***all*** configuration is the default configuration with clustering support and other enterprise extensions.

If you only want a specific subset of JBoss services, then start with the minimal?

Or you can [configure your own](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossas/freezone/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/beta500/html/ch04s02.html)?

Comment: In newer versions there is also a server configuration mentioned in the [documentation][docs] called 'web' which is somewhere between minimal and default - just enough to deploy and serve a WAR web app.

[docs]: http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossas/freezone/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html_single/index.html#The_JBoss_Server___A_Quick_Tour-Server_Configurations

Answer (score 2):

I was able to lower JBoss's initial memory footprint for the **default** profile by over 100MB by following some of the steps from the JBoss community wiki.
Details including how much memory you can save with each step here: http://www.clickonchris.com/2011/06/tuning-reducing-jboss-memory-footprint/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the latest version of JBoss (version 6).  I think it uses less memory, though I could be wrong.

Comment: This is true.  At least one of the steps I outline to reduce memory usage for JBoss 5 (remove debug MBeans) is configured by default in JBoss 6.